# Why is my loop ending after task cancellation?

Tags: c#, async-await, discord.net, cancellationtokensource

I have a music queue manager that plays the next music if the queue is not empty. I also have a "skip" function that stops the current music by cancelling the current task. To stop the music, I create and forward a CancellationTokenSource.Token to **PlayMusicAsync() function**. When the task "PlayMusicAsync()" is cancelled, the CancellationTokenSource is reseted and the loop ends, instead of play the next song.

**MusicQueueManager.cs:**

```cs
    public class MusicQueueManager
    {
        private CancellationTokenSource _cts = new();
        private readonly MusicPlayer _musicPlayer;

        public MusicQueueManager(MusicPlayer musicPlayer)
        {
            _musicPlayer = musicPlayer;
        }

        public List<YoutubeMediaInfo> MusicQueue { get; private set; } = new();
        public bool IsPlaying { get; private set; } = false;
        public bool HasNextSong => MusicQueue.Count > 0;

        public async Task StartPlayingAsync(IAudioClient audioClient, SocketCommandContext context)
        {
            IsPlaying = true;

            while (HasNextSong)
            {
                var nextSong = PopSong();

                if (nextSong is null)
                {
                    await context.Message.ReplyAsync("Error.");
                    continue;
                }

                try
                {
                    await _musicPlayer.PlayMusicAsync(nextSong, audioClient, context, _cts)
                }
                finally
                {
                    _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                }

                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }

            IsPlaying = false;
        }

        public void SkipSong()
        {
            _cts.Cancel();
        }
    }
```

**MusicPlayer.cs:**

```cs
public class MusicPlayer
    {
        public async Task PlayMusicAsync(YoutubeMediaInfo youtubeMediaInfo, IAudioClient audioClient, SocketCommandContext context, CancellationTokenSource cts)
        {
            var youtube = new YoutubeClient();

            var streamInfo = youtubeMediaInfo.StreamManifest?.GetAudioOnlyStreams().GetWithHighestBitrate();

            if (streamInfo is null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var stream = await youtube.Videos.Streams.GetAsync(streamInfo);

            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            await Cli.Wrap("ffmpeg")
                       .WithArguments(" -hide_banner -loglevel panic -i pipe:0 -ac 2 -f s16le -ar 48000 pipe:1")
                       .WithStandardInputPipe(PipeSource.FromStream(stream))
                       .WithStandardOutputPipe(PipeTarget.ToStream(memoryStream))
                   .ExecuteAsync();

            using var discord = audioClient.CreatePCMStream(AudioApplication.Mixed);
            try
            {
                await discord.WriteAsync(memoryStream.ToArray().AsMemory(0, (int)memoryStream.Length), cts.Token);
            }
            finally
            {
                await discord.FlushAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried a solution that adds **.ContinueWith(x => { return; })** to **PlayMusicAsync()** and it worked well, but I don't know why.

**Code Snippet:**

```cs
public async Task StartPlayingAsync(IAudioClient audioClient, SocketCommandContext context)
        {
            IsPlaying = true;

            while (HasNextSong)
            {
                var nextSong = PopSong();

                if (nextSong is null)
                {
                    await context.Message.ReplyAsync("Erro.");
                    continue;
                }

                try
                {
                    await _musicPlayer.PlayMusicAsync(nextSong, audioClient, context, _cts).ContinueWith(x => { return; });
                }
                finally
                {
                    _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                }

                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }

            IsPlaying = false;
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried to add a `catch` block to that try/finally?

Comment: Cancelling an asynchronous operation typically results in an exception, unless the operation is explicitly written to return without throwing, returning a flag or indicator instead. It's your own code that replaces the CancellationTokenSource with a new one in `finally`, thus "resetting" it. In this case, everything depends on `discord.WriteAsync` and whether it will throw or not

Comment: Where does `discord.WriteAsync` come from? Is this a .NET client library for Discord? Shouldn't it have an API for stopping or pausing instead of cancelling?

Answer (score 1):

Upon cancellation it's most likely that `await _musicPlayer.PlayMusicAsync` throws the whole `while` loop "stops" (`StartPlayingAsync` exits with an exception).

In order to keep the loop going you need to catch `OperationCanceledException`:

```
try
{  
    await _musicPlayer.PlayMusicAsync(nextSong, audioClient, context, 
}
catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
{
    // Reste cts here
}
```

---

BTW. There is no need for `PlayMusicAsync` to accept a token source, and normally a method like this would accept just a token.